How to prioritize power sources for SD card and ESP32 in a dual-supply system?
I have a 5V power source derived from an AC mains connection and a USB power source used for reading an SD card. The SD card also communicates with an ESP32 and other components in the system. I’ve already converted the 5V supply to 3.3V using AMS1117 to power the SD card, ESP32, and other components.
I want to design a circuit to handle the following power-supply scenarios:
When both the AC-derived 5V and USB are connected:
The SD card should only be powered by the AC-derived supply.
The ESP32 and other components should remain powered by the AC-derived supply as well.
When the AC-derived 5V is off, but the USB is connected:
Only the SD card should be powered by the USB supply.
The ESP32 and other components should remain off.
USB is working as a SD Card reader.
What would be the best way to implement such a system?
Are there any specific ICs or circuits you’d recommend for this kind of power prioritization and isolation? I would like to make it as simple as possible

… and very many other similar questions. Search for "power switch USB external" or such on this site, you'll literally find hundreds of answers.

The question is, why do you want to power only the SD card if there is nothing to communicate with it? It makes no sense to do that, and connecting powered and unpowered chips is generally a nightmare to avoid back-feeding and damage to them.

Maybe the idea is to let the SD finish its write when losing power, but without more information... it would be preferable to keep both SD and ESP32 powered, and when losing mains power, have ESP32 finish its business and go to sleep instead of powering off. Also if the USB power source is a powerbank, if the load is low current, it will turn itself off...

I want to power the sd card when system is off so that i can fetch the contents of the sd card even when system is off

OK so the USB connection is actually a SD card reader? Are you using some kind of multiplexer so ESP32 and USB card reader don't conflict when talking to the SD card?

yes exactly the usb connection is a SD card reader. and no i am not using any multiplexer but i think what you have said is a valid issue. any idea how can i solve it? even i am clueless now

We call that an XY problem: you ask a question about issue X, but you're really trying to solve problem Y and... it turns out X isn't actually the best solution for Y ;) Having active signals on pins of unpowered chips is always a problem. On the ESP32 side you can solve it by turning the pins into inputs and going to sleep when USB is connected. On the SD card reader side I'm not sure, can you post the datasheet?

its a normal sd card holder
